# Office365 scheduling meetings with out of office users

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, calendar

Is it possible to disable create appointment or meeting if required attendee is out of office at proposed time? There is small warning that meeting is in conflict with other appointment but its not really visible and it isn't immediately clear which user is out of office at that time and users tend to ignore this warning. Scheduling assistant also doesn't mark someone as out of office, its just displayed in table as name.

It doesn't have to be company-wide setting, can single user set something like this so he cannot be invited if he already has something scheduled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to disable create appointment or meeting if required attendee is out of office

No, such functionality doesn't exist. Also, as you want it to affect others' pc, general workarounds (VBA, 3rd egy plug in) won't apply

Best you can do is to request this as new feature.

I'm the meantime, if you consistently reject meetings when you aren't available - maybe also politely ask them to check your availability - people will start respecting your schedule.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, out of office users can set the time to display when they are out of office in Outlook client, so that other colleagues can know their status when arranging meetings.

For more information, please refer to: [Add time away from the office to coworkers' Outlook calendars](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-time-away-from-the-office-to-coworkers-outlook-calendars-69fe38aa-7b5f-4225-8b69-47f47092e65e). Hope to help you!

Comment: Our of office message affects only current status, not future when meetings are likely organised